# order by case with multiple order criteria

Tags: mysql, order-by, case

I would like to know how to use multiple order columnes with case. For example case 1, order by FirstName, GivenName case 2 order by GivenName, FirstName.

I tried this, but it looks like the colon introduce an error

Order by case
     when 1 then FirstName, GivenName 
     else GivenName, FirstName end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case is supposed to return one value, not a tuple. Beside, you should compare 1 with something. If you want conditional ordering you can do that with two case statements:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN FirstName ELSE GivenName END
       , CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN GivenName ELSE FirstName END
```

Comment: Excelente.... It worked.... All that I needed was to use two separate case statements whitin order by

Answer (score 2):

For multiple conditional ORDER BY statements:

```
ORDER BY CASE category WHEN 0 THEN concat(cName,', ',bName) END DESC,
         CASE category WHEN 1 THEN concat(aName,', ',bName,', ',cName) END DESC,
         CASE category WHEN 2 THEN concat(bName,', ',aName,', ',cName) END DESC";
```